# Check the exit status of last command in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

Does anybody know how to check the status of the last executed command (exit code) in ipython?

Comment: Are you staring the command within python using something like os.system?  Or are you running command foo, and then running your python script?

Comment: just using ipython as shell, and running commands with !cmd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about running commands from IPython using the `!` escape:

```
In[1]: !echo hello
hello

In[2]:
```

Using Google I found the documentation and there is no mention of the exit status of the command being captured anywhere.  Using `dir()` I looked for a variable name that might be holding that information and I didn't find anything.  I tried the `x = !ls` syntax and `x` gets set to a list of output lines from the command; there is no exit status in there.

In short, I don't think IPython is even capturing this information.  At this point I would want to check the source code to IPython to try to figure out anything else.

You can always just run the command with `os.system()` and get an exit status from that.

```
In[1]: !launch_eva
launch_eva: could not open AT Field

In[2]: import os
In[3]: exit_status = os.system("launch_eva")
launch_eva: could not open AT Field

In[4]: exit_status
3

In[5]:
```

Thus we see the command `launch_eva` is returning exit status 3 when it can't open an AT Field.

It seems like this is something that IPython should be saving.  There are plenty of little hidden variables.  You should file a feature request about this.

NOTE: This was tested in IPython 0.10.1 on Ubuntu.  Another answer, by "piotr", says that exit code will be captured in IPython 0.11, due to release soon.  I cloned the source code from the Git repository at https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git and tested it with `python ipython.py`; as piotr said, the exit status is saved in a variable called `_exit_status`.

Answer (score 16):

It should be stored as `_exit_code` after you run the command (at least in the upcoming v0.11 release).

Comment: as of 0.13.2, this works, but not if I capture stdout with "a = !false" (if I capture stdout `_exit_code` does not change). Anyone knows if there is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the command result in variable and you can check the variable whether it is present in locals() function or not.
for example1:-

```
var1="hello"
if 'var1' in locals():
print "status is false i.e 0"
else :
print "status is false i.e 1"
```

In this case the variable will be printed as hello, if you will not assign var1 to any value it will go to else loop.
example2:-

```
var1=subprocess.check_output('ps -aef | grep -i dmesg -wT | grep -v grep',shell=True)
if 'var1' in locals():
print "status is true i.e 0"
else :
print "status is false i.e 1"
```