# Is there "set -e" equivalent for ipython

Tags: python, bash, ipython

`set -e` at the beginning of the `bash` script instructs bash to fail the whole script on first failure of any command inside.

Is there any equivalent to use with `ipython` script which invokes bash commands through `!command`?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [check the exit status of last command in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755794/check-the-exit-status-of-last-command-in-ipython), there is an `_exit_code` variable. What you want to do is thus equivalent to adding an `assert _exit_code==0` after each shell command. I have not found a feature to do the check automatically, but I'm not that familiar with ipython.

Comment: Thanks, that may work although I can't imagine doing this in long term.  Hope that someone finds simpler and prettier solution.

Comment: Note that `a = !false` does **not** change `_exit_code`.