# Check to see if Linux program has stopped running

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

How could I make a python script exit itself when another script exits?

Let's say the second script ran ssh, tried to connect and then ssh stopped running because it wasn't able to connect. Is there a way that I could get the first script to know that the second couldn't connect?

Comment: ***"exit itself when another script exits?"***: Are you the owner of **both** scripts?

Comment: @stovfl nope, someone changed my question so

Comment: ***"nope"***: How do you start the **second** script? Are you able to notice the **exit** of the **second** script? ***"someone changed my question"***: [Edit] it again and add relevant information.

Comment: @stovfl let's say that i wanted to write a python script, that would be able to tell if ssh was able to successfully connect to a server or not, how would i go about doing that, let's say that the ssh command stopped running after it failed to login to a server, how would i be able to tell that it stopped running?

Comment: ***" be able to tell if ssh was able to successfully connect"***: Couldn't you simple `try:` to connect and if `except:` **exit** the Python script?

Comment: @stovfl doesn't try and except only works for errors? This wouldn't be an error within the command it would just be like ssh stopped it's self after it couldn't login. Like it's a common functionality for ssh and i want to be able to tell if ssh stopped running, like just completely stopped. No errors.

Comment: ***"only works for errors? "***: It's all wild guessing, you have to [edit] your question and show,per the [mcve] guidelines, your Python script how it interacts with `ssh`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in Shell Scripts `$?` does the magic by checking the exit status of last command executed. You can build any required logic around this.

For python, seems like there is an article already recorded here [Check the exit status of last command in ipython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755794/check-the-exit-status-of-last-command-in-ipython)

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing the specific problem or environment, I would look into the signal module and/or psutil.